# Display settings not saving on 19.04 upon reboot

Tags: graphics, display, settings, 19.04

I'm using proprietary NVIDIA drivers for my 2080 Ti running Ubuntu 19.04

Every time I reboot all of the display settings are lost.
Monitor positioning is flipped and scaling is set back to 100%.

I have tried almost everything on the forums/stack (eg: getting settings from nvidia-settings and putting them in xorg.conf, scripts to flip display, reinstalling nvidia drivers, trying older drivers) but have gotten nowhere.
Any ideas?

Comment: Trying older drivers for a brand new Nvidia line of products is likely to be a very bad idea. Trying the latest is probably the way to go.

Comment: Hey, currently using the latest drivers. I didn't want to go back very far since they are a brand new video card when I purged it Installed its additional drivers and detected the video card correctly. Still does not save graphical settings.